# Admob Interstitial Ad setup

Tags: java, admob

I've created an admob account and I followed how to create intersistial ad .Ive seen how to implement sdk and how to create ad unit , but unfortunately I can't see it works , this is the code :

**Main Activity**

```
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

 interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());


interstitialAd.show();
```

build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

hope you can help me.

Comment: it take some time to show ad after create ads on admob console

Comment: thank you , but its not working , I don't know what to do , help please

Comment: what you think is the problem?

Comment: Wait for few hours, abmob Tek time for show ads after creat it

Comment: I've waited 24 hours to see if its work but nothing , I don't understand what to do .

Comment: maybe you can give me code example , it will very helpful , thanx

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `interstitialAd.show()` after ad load.

Call after some time first check then show

```
if( interstitialAd.isloaded()){
interstitialAd.show()
}
```